# K6 script failing in azure devops

Tags: performance, azure-devops, load-testing, k6

**Setup**

We are using [K6](https://k6.io/) tool for Load testing our API.
Locally scripts work perfectly fine with virtual users up to 50

**problem statement**

While running the same script in Azure devops using [K6](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k6.k6-load-test) task  and virtual user 15 for duration 60s most of the request (almost 90%) is failing because of timeout and following is the error :

**level=warning msg="Request Failed" error="Get "https://xxxxx": dial tcp xxxx: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."**

Not sure

**a) What is causing the timeout?**

**b) What are the other options?**

PS: Api is behind Api Management Service in Azure and load test works locally fine even on 10 times higher load

Comment: What kind of agent you were using, self-host or host agent? What if you reduce the numbers of user from 15 to 5. Did you still get same error on Azure DevOps after this.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Yes, we are using host agent(Azure pipeline). And we are getting same error if we reduce the number of users also.

Comment: Likely, no requests what so ever make it then, and the reason for 90% is that the rest are interrupted. Does that match your observations? In any case, I'd suggest you put a curl step in your pipeline and curl the same URL with the exact same params, just to verify whether it is k6 or the network configuration that is at fault here.

Comment: `And we are getting same error if we reduce the number of users also.` Agreed with simme, this seems not touch the load limitation. Kindly check if it's a network related issue. Make sure `https://xxxxx` is a public touched and trust list.

Comment: @simme Thank you very much. I'll try this and let u know.

Comment: Hi @chandanprasad Any update on this ticket, have you figured out it?

Comment: We are now experiencing the same thing; these tests worked before.  Locally, I've discovered I now need to execute `export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider` before running the tests.  I haven't figured out the online equivalent or whether that helps yet.